# else no funciona dentro de while al hacer consulta en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, php7

Estos es parte de un login pero al momento de poner la contraseña bien entra y todo pero el else es el que esta causando problemas ya que no se ejecuta les dejo el codigo y espero me puedan ayudar. Saludos!

$usuario="delcaspa";
        $contra="Maxion2020";

```
                $consulta = sqlsrv_query($con, "select * from portal_maxionwheels.usuario_portal where alias_up='$usuario' and contrasena_up='$contra' and estatus_up='1';");
                while( $resultado = sqlsrv_fetch_object( $consulta )) {
                              $resultado->id_up;
                              $resultado->contrasena_up;
                              $resultado->alias_up;
                              $resultado->nom_up;
                              $resultado->apellidos_up;

                            if($usuario===$resultado->alias_up and $contra===$resultado->contrasena_up){
                                $_SESSION['id'] = $resultado->id_up;
                                $_SESSION['id'] = $resultado->contrasena_up;
                                $_SESSION['alias'] = $resultado->alias_up;
                                $_SESSION['nombre'] = $resultado->nom_up;
                                $_SESSION['ape'] = $resultado->apellidos_up;
                                header("location: indexadmin.php");
                                echo "ya entraste wey";
                            }else{
                                  echo "<script>
                                       setTimeout(function() {
                                       alert('Usuario o Contraseña Incorrecta');
                                            location.href = '../index.php';
                                       }, 10);
                                   </script>";
                    }
                        }
```

Comment: Si haces un `echo` sin el alert en el `else` tampoco funciona?

Comment: Como dice @Bicho, prueba sin el código Javascript. Y, te recomendaría que evites mezclar código de servidor y de cliente, es mucho mejor usar Ajax para comunicarte entre cliente y servidor.

Comment: @Bicho lo intente tal como comentaste pero no funciona saque el if del while y funciona correctamente lo que se es que estoy haciendo mal en while para que el codigo no funcione ;(, A. Cedano gracias por tu ayuda bro!